# Click event not triggered of dynamically added div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added  a div dynamically  into HTML,

When i have tried to  trigger the  click event of same element

what i have tried  till yet is below   ::

```
$(function(){
         $("#id").bind("click",function(){
             alert("hi");
          })
});
```

i have also tried to use "on" instead of  "bind" but it doesn't work.

but when i have  write  simple , it works  fine

```
<div onclick="javascript:testFunction();"></div>
```

Comment: You need to attach the event after the element is inserted into the DOM. You can try to bind again after the element is inserted ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegate event using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), you can give the static parent of element that is supposed to be added after execution of binding code.

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click", "#id",function(){
         alert("hi");
    });
});
```

**Delegated events**

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: If there is a parent container the div is added to, and that will exist when the script runs, then you could also replace the reference to document in Adil's code with "{selector}" where {selector} is the jQuery selector for that container.